# how to import strongloop based api into json or yaml specification

Tags: json, strongloop, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an API who is generarted using loopback / strongloop and its running as follows.

[image]

and i want to export the the generated api into yaml or json so that i want to reuse it in another application. **i m looking for swagger.json file.**

SO in sawgger you get your json from your running api by going to localhost:3300/api-docs. How do i get it from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that simply by typing

`localhost:3300/explorer/swagger.json` , 
you need to download the **json file** and load that into [editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io) using file import then download it as YAML to feed into your restAPi ppliaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

`localhost:3300/explorer/resources` to get a list of all resources and `localhost:3300/explorer/resource/ModelPluralName` to get swagger for specific resource.

Also you can click on "Raw" link in your API explorer.

*Assuming of course that your application is running on localhost port 3300.